# Which Microsoft Word (and Excel) Interop Assembly or DLL Should I Reference?

Tags: .net, excel, dll, ms-word, automation

I'm using VB.NET and the .NET 3.5 framework.

I am trying to automate word and excel using their respective PIAs to get intellisense help, then (since the users don't have the PIA assemblies/DLLs installed) remove the references so that it will work as a COM object call without throwing an error.

I found this article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57.aspx
but it doesn't really help me with what version of the assembly/DLL I should use. When I go to add a reference I see something like these:

[image: first pane]

then

[image: Second pane]

then

[image: third pane]

Notice all of these highlighted ones all sound similar and there are multiple versions of the assembly. The link I started with suggests the name of the DLL in association to the product version (like WORD version 12 --- Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll) but doesn't say what *version* of the PIA assembly. So **how do I know which one to use?**

And a better question: why is this not **OBVIOUS** somewhere? All I want is Microsoft to say "hey, you want to automate a mail merge with Word 2007? Use [insert meaningful DLL name here (PIA or "tools" assembly?)]. By the way, you can get that DLL here ["here" hyper-linked to the download I need]. Working with computers that may have 2007 or 2010 installed? Make sure you have both DLLs (if that is the case), and here is how you test for it: [insert helpful example].

(e.g. "For Word 14 (i.e. Word 2010), use the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word DLL version 12.0.0.0" (is this the case? I don't know.)) *That should be obvious*, and it does not appear to be so.

Maybe it *is* obvious? Is the version of the DLL the same as the version of the program? (i.e. Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word DLL version 12.0.0.0 =?= WORD version 12)

Maybe I am over-thinking this, but it is still not obvious to me. I'll be happy if you can answer the first question, but if you can explain both, that would be better.

Comment: +1. It's a good question, esp. for those who are just starting out working with this. See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Word for version numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the class browser to see if the DLL you add exposes the functionality you want (just like you do for *every other reference you ever add*.

> why is this not OBVIOUS somewhere?

So, you want everything you could possibly ever create with the office integration documented somewhere? That doesn't make sense!

Comment: You misunderstood the part I want to be obvious. I want to know WHAT VERSION OF THE DLL (as pictured above) GOES TO WHAT VERSION OF THE PROGRAM. (as the title of the article suggests) (e.g. "For Word 14 (i.e. Word 2010), use the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word DLL version 12.0.0.0" (is this the case? I don't know.)) *That should be obvious*, and it does not appear to be so.

Comment: Office 12 was Office 2007. Office 14 was Office 2010. I don't see where the confusion lies.

Comment: Maybe it is this simple... I just need someone to clarify this. My understanding is that you can have/use a PIA that is of a different version than the program it references. For example, you can use Outlook 2010 or 2007 or even 2003 with Exchange 2010. Obviously you would get the most feature support using Outlook 2010, because Outlook 2010 was designed at the same time and specifically for Exchange 2010. So with PIAs - which **PIA version** was designed specifically for Word 2007? And which **version** was designed for Word 2010? Etc. etc.

Comment: @Watki02: Well it's strangely interesting that the two versions you see on your box correspond to the two shipping version numbers of both products. I don't see any reason why they'd differ. Office exposes COM interfaces, not .NET interfaces. The interop assemblies just smooth over some of the COM stuff for you. But each PIA version cannot be specifically tied to a particular Office release because the different releases support different COM interfaces. You might only use features of the 2010 PIA that work back to 2003 and be just fine. You have to install Office and find out.

Answer (score 4):

Billy basically answered your question

Office 2010=14.x.x.x

Office 2007=12.x.x.x

Office 2003=11.x.x.x

Office xp=10.x.x.x

Before that, there weren't any PIA's so you'd have to make your own.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of ways to skin the cat known as "how do I know which object does X".

1. use the object browser and search for the methods you desire.
2. Code it and then add assemblies one at a time - slow and inefficient, but it works

As for figuring out particular bits, Microsoft MSDN, Support, etc all have resources. For mail merge, for example, I found this:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301659

It is fairly easy to follow references for the code, if mail merge is the issue.

As for the "why is this not obvious somewhere" comment: The Word obects are fairly well documented. Perhaps not to the level you wish to automate Intellisense, but this is a fringe case, IMO. I have been programming the .NET Framework since before the 1.0 release and have yet to have a business case for what you are doing. I also don't know of anyone who has had this type of business case. Following the 80/20 rule, I am not surprised there is not a handholding exercise on this one ... or even full documentation.

Comment: Your link takes me to a C# article on automating XP stuff... the download page is helpful. You seem to have dodged the issue of what version of the DLL equals what version of the program. And I'm not trying to automate intellisense (how does that even make sense?), I am using the PIA to get intellisense help during coding. Also, I would think the very act of having a PIA would necessitate an explanation as to what version of the program it is applicable to, which in my mind is every possible business case...
Your first 2 bullet points seem helpful. I'll look into that.

Answer (score 1):

It's in the documentation, e.g. [DocumentClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.documentclass%28v=office.11%29.aspx):

> Namespace: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
>   Assembly: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word (in microsoft.office.interop.word.dll)

If it has any dependencies on the other assemblies then it ought to add them in itself, or it might prompt you for them at runtime to add.

I'm not sure there's a definitive guide to picking which one, but I'd go for

- the oldest version of `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` that includes all the functionality you need, so you're compatible with as many Word versions as possible
- prefer assemblies built with the correct .NET version - I've seen problems with 1.1 assemblies against 4.0 (although not Interop assemblies) but I think generally 1.1 with 2.0 (=3.5's runtime version under the covers) should be OK.

Comment: Excellent point on using the oldest version that includes what you'll need. This is esp true if you want to target multiple versions of Word (or any office app for that matter). To access functionallity in any newer version then, you have to use late binding. Not ideal, but there you are.